# index single product in EE 1.10.1.1

Tags: price, indexing, magento-enterprise, reindex

I need to reindex individual products after updating price in EE 1.10.1.1 - this post:
[Reindex single product](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/4107/reindex-single-product) shows a way to do that in CE 1.6 but I think EE 1.10 might correspond to CE 1.5.

Anyway, I believe I might have to go directly to the database tables to do this but I haven't had any success finding the exact tables that need to be changed to update the price.  I have tried catalog_product_flat_1, catalog_product_entity_decimal, and a few others.  I clear cache but the prices aren't changing.

Any thoughts would be appreciated.

Comment: Any reason you can't just set the price index to be update on save?

Comment: This isn't a price change in the admin.  It is a command line script. (plus we have a massive product catalog so re-indexing is very time consuming and causes issues on the front-end)

Comment: Makes no difference whether it is executed via the CLI or the GUI. A `$product->save()` will trigger a re-index.