# How to reindex one product from observer?

Tags: magento-1.9

I have an observer function that calls before product save. I want to reindex one single product (the one that it is edited in observer).

Comment: Refer the http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/4107/reindex-single-product

Comment: It's not the same thing . Aparrently that thing dosn't work in Observer.

Comment: What do you expect to happen, if you reindex **before** saving?

Comment: I'm reindexing after now. And still nothing