# Whether possible to reindex Catalog URL Rewrites for some products?

Tags: magento-1.7

Daily 5 to 10 products are uploaded in website. So when we reindex Catalog URL Rewrites, it takes so much time and website becomes slow and down.

I thought is it possible to reindex only 10 products instead indexing all.

Can anyone explain what will be the consequences?

Whether it is safe or not?

Comment: If you set the indexers to automatically reindex, you shouldn't have to reindex all every time, it will reindex when the product is saved.

Comment: @JulienLachal - Update on save, slows down our website so we have done it Manual Update.

Comment: The thing is that trying to reindex products will impact other indexes such as flat catalog, product attributes, prices and URLs.

Comment: @JulienLachal - Yes, I have indexed all other indexes and product is also visible on frontend. Now problem is only with Catalog URL  Rewrites since it is taking so much time to reindex.

Comment: Why don't you set up a cron that will reindex the URLs every night?

Comment: @JulienLachal - Yes, I have done that

Comment: On a 15k+ product with 500+ categories it only takes me about 2 minutes to reindex URLs. I don't understand the issue with doing it at night, is your website that big?

Comment: @JulienLachal - I have only 6500 products and near about 200 categories but still it takes so much time and slows down the website. Any guesses why it takes so much time?

Comment: Not a clue, I don't know about your server configuration either. But if it takes so much time, why not do it at night?

Comment: @JulienLachal - Server specifications

cPanel Version                   - 60.0 (build 26)
Apache Version                 - 2.2.31
PHP Version                        - 5.4.45
MySQL Version                  - 5.5.52-cll
Architecture                        - x86_64
Operating System             - linux

Comment: @JulienLachal - Yes we do cron job at night only

Comment: @JulienLachal In core_url_rewrite table I have 1728682 records.

Comment: @jassi i have no idea about your site, but generally site will load faster when   index is in `automatic reindex` , so if you keep that no need to do `reindex management` again & again. when you need to upload thousnds of products than only its require to keep in `manual mode` so that products will upload fastly, later you can change to `automatic index`, but that is not your case.  not sure you are looking for these [link1](http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/4107/reindex-single-product) for reindex some products.

Comment: @jassi also for faster reindexing - [link2](https://github.com/SchumacherFM/Magento-FastIndexer) , [link3](http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/8487/how-to-speed-up-reindexing-process) & [link4](http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/3028/permanent-solution-for-the-common-indexing-issue)

Comment: @BabyinMagento thanks, I will go through the links and check