# Reindex a single category in magento 1

Tags: magento-1.9, php, reindex

I want to re-index a single category in Magento 1.

The method given in [this post](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/4107/reindex-single-product) is not working for reindexing categories

Is there a way to do it through code?